# Stripe error: STPToken? is not a subtype of STPToken

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I am implementing `Stripe` in swift, and I am now trying to get the `token` from the card that was input. Like this :

```
var Client : STPAPIClient?
Client?.createTokenWithCard(card, completion: { (token: STPToken!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

})
```

and I am getting the error:

> STPToken? is not a subtype of STPToken

Any ideas would be great, thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue